# Why can you overwrite true but not false in namespaces?

Tags: php, constants

According to my tests on http://3v4l.org/ZCJWA following example (For PHP 5.3.10 - 5.4.6):

```
<?php
namespace Foo;
define('Foo\\true', false);
define('Foo\\false', true);

var_dump(
    true,
    false,
    1 === 1,
    1 === 0
);
```

will return:

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Why can you overwrite `true` with `false` but not `false` with `true`?

Comment: because true is also now false, false is overwritten with false?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After your 1st `define`, `true` is now defined to be `false`, so `Foo\\false` gets set to  `false`.

To get it working as expected, you should should be setting `Foo\\true` and `Foo\\false` to the [global space](http://php.net/manual/language.namespaces.global.php) values of `true` and `false` respectively:

```
define('Foo\\true', \false);
define('Foo\\false', \true);
```

Comment: Thank you! My mistake. http://3v4l.org/OrLCh